# Registering a custom CodeInsight manager to C++Builder without initialization/finalization sections

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I'm trying to register a custom CodeInsight manager into C++Builder 10.1.2 Berlin.

Because there's nothing like *Objects Pascal*'s `initialization` and `finalization` sections in C++, e.g.

```
var
  codeManagerIndex: Integer;

{...}

initialization
  codeManagerIndex := (BorlandIDEServices as IOTACodeInsightServices).AddCodeInsightManager(TMyCodeInsightManager.Create);

finalization
  (borlandIDEServices as IOTACodeInsightServices).RemoveCodeInsightManager(codeManagerIndex);
end.
```

I tried reproducing their behavior with a custom `runner` class with constructor/destructor:

```cpp
class Runner
{
public:
    int FCodeManagerIndex;

    _di_IOTACodeInsightServices CIS;

    Runner() {
        if (BorlandIDEServices->Supports(CIS))
            FCodeManagerIndex = CIS->AddCodeInsightManager(new TMyCodeInsightManager);
    }

    ~Runner() {
        if (BorlandIDEServices->Supports(CIS))
            CIS->RemoveCodeInsightManager(FCodeManagerIndex);
    }
};


#pragma argsused
extern "C" int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
{
    Runner Run;
    return 1;
}
```

I can compile my simple implementation but when I try to install the package the following things are happening:

- 1st try: Error message: *Can't load package ... mypackage.bpl* -  A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
- 2nd try: *An exception (C0000005) occured during DllEntryPoint or DllMain in module: ... mypackage.bpl* ... then the IDE crashes.

Is this a wrong way to register?
What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. I get a *[TLIB Warning] Warning: library was too large for page size, rebuilt with page size 32* warning when compiling, but I'm quite sure that this can't be the reason for my errors. (?)

Comment: Don't you do this in the constructor of class. Then declare a static variable. The constructor runs at startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there's nothing like Objects Pascal's `initialization` and `finalization` sections in C++

Actually, there is.  In C++Builder, you can use [`#pragma startup` and `#pragma exit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pragma_exit_and_pragma_startup) to execute user-defined functions:

```cpp
static int FCodeManagerIndex = -1;    

void DoRegister() {
    _di_IOTACodeInsightServices CIS;
    if (BorlandIDEServices->Supports(CIS)) {
        FCodeManagerIndex = CIS->AddCodeInsightManager(new TMyCodeInsightManager);        
    }
}
#pragma startup DoRegister

void DoUnregister() {
    _di_IOTACodeInsightServices CIS;
    if ((FCodeManagerIndex != -1) && BorlandIDEServices->Supports(CIS)) {
        CIS->RemoveCodeInsightManager(FCodeManagerIndex);
    }
}
#pragma exit DoUnregister

#pragma argsused
extern "C" int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Alternatively, since you ready declared a class to handle your registration, you can simply move your class variable into global static memory so its constructor runs at startup and destructor runs at shutdown:

```cpp
class Runner
{
public:
    int FCodeManagerIndex;

    Runner() : FCodeManagerIndex(-1) {
        _di_IOTACodeInsightServices CIS;
        if (BorlandIDEServices->Supports(CIS)) {
            FCodeManagerIndex = CIS->AddCodeInsightManager(new TMyCodeInsightManager);
        }
    }

    ~Runner() {
        _di_IOTACodeInsightServices CIS;
        if ((FCodeManagerIndex != -1) && BorlandIDEServices->Supports(CIS)) {
            CIS->RemoveCodeInsightManager(FCodeManagerIndex);
        }
    }
};

static Runner Run;

#pragma argsused
extern "C" int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Declaring the class variable inside of `_libmain()` is useless since the destructor will be called when the variable goes out of scope when `_libmain()` exits, thus unregistering the manager immediately after registering it. So the variable has to survive for as long as the package is loaded in memory.

Comment: Thanks again, Remy.

Comment: Now here is a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932738/registering-a-custom-codeinsight-manager-what-am-i-doing-wrong).