# Registering a custom CodeInsight manager - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

This is a subsequent question to [my fist one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922887/registering-a-custom-codeinsight-manager-to-cbuilder-without-initialization-fi), asking how to register a custom *CodeInsight* manager to the IDE with C++Builder.

I switched my code to Remy Lebeau's version with the  `#pragma startup` and `#pragma exit`directives.

What now happens when I try to use it (see my code below) is this:

With *CodeGuard* set to *active*:

- I hit **F9** -> Project compiles well (except for *[TLIB Warning] Warning: library was too large for page size, rebuilt with page size 32*)
- A second instance of *bds.exe* starts (because i set it as the host app)
- In the 2nd instance I try to install my package wich results in the following error:
  [image: Error1]
  [image: Stack1]

I deactivate *CodeGuard* in the project debugging settings and try it again and now it seems to work, as I can see a sequence of MessageBoxes:

1. TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::TMyCodeInsightSymbolList
2. TMyCodeInsightManager::TMyCodeInsightManager
3. TMyCodeInsightManager::GetIDString
4. TMyCodeInsightManager::GetIDString
5. TMyCodeInsightManager::GetIDString
6. TMyCodeInsightManager::GetIDString
7. TMyCodeInsightManager::GetIDString

Now I create a new *VCL Forms Application* in the debugging instance and enter

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{
    this->|
}
```

in TForm1's constructor.

The resulting *MessageBoxes*:

1. TMyCodeInsightManager::HandlesFile
2. TMyCodeInsightManager::GetEnabled
3. TMyCodeInsightManager::AllowCodeInsight
4. TMyCodeInsightManager::EditorTokenValidChars
5. TMyCodeInsightManager::PreValidateCodeInsight
6. TMyCodeInsightManager::EditorTokenValidChars
7. TMyCodeInsightManager::InvokeCodeCompletion
8. TMyCodeInsightManager::GetSymbolList
9. TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetCount
10. **TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::~TMyCodeInsightSymbolList**
11. TMyCodeInsightManager::GetSymbolList
12. **Error**:
    [image: Error2]
    [image: Stack2]

It drives me crazy...so **what the heck am I doing wrong here**?

{...}

Furthermore, in the IDE setting in the 2nd instance at *Editor Options* -> *CodeInsight* I see my new entry in the ComboBox *Source file type* but when I select it, there's an out of range error, so I think the IDE is missing some registry entries for my completion manager or stuff. Am I right?

Now, here's my code:

**my_completion.cpp**

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma package(smart_init)

#include "my_codeinsight_manager.h"

static int FCodeManagerIndex = -1;

void DoRegister()
{
    _di_IOTACodeInsightServices CIS;

    if (BorlandIDEServices->Supports(CIS))
        FCodeManagerIndex = CIS->AddCodeInsightManager(new TMyCodeInsightManager);
}
#pragma startup DoRegister

void DoUnregister()
{
    _di_IOTACodeInsightServices CIS;

    if ((FCodeManagerIndex != -1) && BorlandIDEServices->Supports(CIS))
        CIS->RemoveCodeInsightManager(FCodeManagerIndex);
}
#pragma exit DoUnregister

#pragma argsused
extern "C" int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
{
    return 1;
}
```

---

**my_codeinsight_manager.h**

```
#ifndef my_codeinsight_managerH
#define my_codeinsight_managerH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <memory>
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <ToolsAPI.hpp>
#include "my_codeinsight_symbollist.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TMyCodeInsightManager : public TCppInterfacedObject<IOTANotifier, IOTACodeInsightManager>
{
public:
    TMyCodeInsightManager();
    virtual __fastcall ~TMyCodeInsightManager();

    String __fastcall GetName();
    String __fastcall GetIDString();
    bool __fastcall GetEnabled();
    void __fastcall SetEnabled(bool AValue) ;
    TSysCharSet __fastcall EditorTokenValidChars(bool APreValidating);
    void __fastcall AllowCodeInsight(bool& Allow, const WideChar AKey);
    bool __fastcall PreValidateCodeInsight(const String AStr);
    bool __fastcall IsViewerBrowsable(int AIndex);
    bool __fastcall GetMultiSelect();
    void __fastcall GetSymbolList(_di_IOTACodeInsightSymbolList& ASymbolList);
    void __fastcall OnEditorKey(WideChar AKey, bool& ACloseViewer, bool& AAccept);
    bool __fastcall HandlesFile(const String AFileName);
    String __fastcall GetLongestItem();
    void __fastcall GetParameterList(_di_IOTACodeInsightParameterList& AParameterList);
    void __fastcall GetCodeInsightType(WideChar AChar, int AElement, TOTACodeInsightType& ACodeInsightType, TOTAInvokeType& AInvokeType);
    bool __fastcall InvokeCodeCompletion(TOTAInvokeType AHowInvoked, String& AStr);
    bool __fastcall InvokeParameterCodeInsight(TOTAInvokeType AHowInvoked, int& ASelectedIndex);
    void __fastcall ParameterCodeInsightAnchorPos(TOTAEditPos& AEdPos);
    int __fastcall ParameterCodeInsightParamIndex(const TOTAEditPos& AEdPos);
    String __fastcall GetHintText(int AHintLine, int AHintCol);
    String __fastcall GetOptionSetName();
    bool __fastcall GotoDefinition(String& AFileName, int& ALineNum, int AIndex=0xFFFFFFFF);
    void __fastcall Done(bool AAccepted, bool& ADisplayParams);

    __property String Name = {read=GetName};
    __property bool MultiSelect = {read=GetMultiSelect};
    __property bool Enabled = {read=GetEnabled, write=SetEnabled};

    /* IOTANotifier */
    void __fastcall AfterSave() {}
    void __fastcall BeforeSave() {}
    void __fastcall Destroyed() {}
    void __fastcall Modified() {}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<TMyCodeInsightSymbolList> FSymbolList;
    TSysCharSet FSysCharSet;
};
```

---

**my_codeinsight_manager.cpp**

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "my_codeinsight_manager.h"
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)


TMyCodeInsightManager::TMyCodeInsightManager()
    :   FSymbolList(std::unique_ptr<TMyCodeInsightSymbolList>(new TMyCodeInsightSymbolList))
{
    FSysCharSet =   TSysCharSet()   << 'A' << 'B' << 'C' << 'D' << 'E' << 'F' << 'G' << 'H' << 'I' << 'J' << 'K'
                                    << 'L' << 'M' << 'N' << 'O' << 'P' << 'Q' << 'R' << 'S' << 'T' << 'U' << 'V' << 'W'
                                    << 'X' << 'Y' << 'Z'
                                    << 'a' << 'b' << 'c' << 'd' << 'e' << 'f' << 'g' << 'h' << 'i' << 'j' << 'k' << 'l'
                                    << 'm' << 'n' << 'o' << 'p' << 'q' << 'r' << 's' << 't' << 'u' << 'v' << 'w' << 'x'
                                    << 'y' << 'z'
                                    << '0' << '1' << '2' << '3' << '4' << '5' << '6' << '7' << '8' << '9'
                                    << '+' << '-' << '*' << '/' << '^' << '\\' << '(' << ')' << '[' << ']' << '{' << '}'
                                    << '=' << '!' << '<' << '>' << '\'' << '\"' << '$' << ',' << ';' << ':' << '5' << '!'
                                    << '&' << '?' << '_' << '#' << '@'
                                    << 0x08 << 0x09 << 0x0B << 0x0C << 0x0D;

    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::TMyCodeInsightManager");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::~TMyCodeInsightManager()
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::~TMyCodeInsightManager");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

String __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GetName()
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GetName");
    return L"MyCodeInsightLanguage";
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

String __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GetIDString()
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GetIDString");
    return L"My.CodeInsight";
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GetEnabled()
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GetEnabled");
    return true;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::SetEnabled(bool AValue)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::SetEnabled");
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

TSysCharSet __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::EditorTokenValidChars(bool APreValidating)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::EditorTokenValidChars");
    return FSysCharSet;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::AllowCodeInsight(bool& AAllow, const WideChar AKey)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::AllowCodeInsight");
    AAllow = true;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::PreValidateCodeInsight(const String AStr)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::PreValidateCodeInsight");
    return true;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::IsViewerBrowsable(int AIndex)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::IsViewerBrowsable");
    return true; // # TO DO #
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GetMultiSelect()
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GetMultiSelect");
    return false;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GetSymbolList(_di_IOTACodeInsightSymbolList& ASymbolList)
{
    ASymbolList = FSymbolList.get();
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GetSymbolList");
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::OnEditorKey(WideChar AKey, bool& ACloseViewer, bool& AAccept)
{
    ACloseViewer = true;
    AAccept = false;
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::OnEditorKey");
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::HandlesFile(const String AFileName)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::HandlesFile");
    String FileExt = ExtractFileExt(AFileName);

    if  (   (FileExt == L".c")
        ||  (FileExt == L".cpp")
        ||  (FileExt == L".h")
        ||  (FileExt == L".hpp")
        ||  (FileExt == L".cc")
        ||  (FileExt == L".cp")
        ||  (FileExt == L".cxx")    )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

String __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GetLongestItem()
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GetLongestItem");
    return String(L"dddddddddddddddddddddd");
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GetParameterList(_di_IOTACodeInsightParameterList& AParameterList)
{
    AParameterList = NULL;
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GetParameterList");
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GetCodeInsightType(WideChar AChar, int AElement, TOTACodeInsightType& ACodeInsightType, TOTAInvokeType& AInvokeType)
{
    AInvokeType = itManual;

    if ( (AElement != atString) && (AChar != 0x0001) && (AElement == atComment) )
    {
        switch (AChar)
        {
            case 0x0000:
                ACodeInsightType = citCodeInsight;
            break;

            case 0x0001:
                ACodeInsightType = citParameterCodeInsight;
            break;

            case 0x0002:
                ACodeInsightType = citBrowseCodeInsight;
            break;

            case 0x0003:
                ACodeInsightType = citHintCodeInsight;
            break;

            case L'.':
                ACodeInsightType = citCodeInsight;
                AInvokeType = itTimer;
            break;

            case L'(':
                ACodeInsightType = citParameterCodeInsight;
                AInvokeType = itTimer;
            break;

            default:
                ACodeInsightType = citNone;
        }
    }
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GetCodeInsightType");
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::InvokeCodeCompletion(TOTAInvokeType AHowInvoked, String& AStr)
{
    switch (AHowInvoked)
    {
        case itAuto:
        break;

        case itManual:
        break;

        case itTimer:
        break;
    }

    AStr = L"IAmASymbolText";

    return true;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::InvokeParameterCodeInsight(TOTAInvokeType AHowInvoked, int&  ASelectedIndex)
{
    switch (AHowInvoked)
    {
        case itAuto:
        break;

        case itManual:
        break;

        case itTimer:
        break;
    }

    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::OnvokeParameterCodeInsight");

    return true; // # TO DO #
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::ParameterCodeInsightAnchorPos(TOTAEditPos& AEdPos)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::ParameterCodeInsightAnchorPos");
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::ParameterCodeInsightParamIndex(const TOTAEditPos& AEdPos)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::ParameterCodeInsightParamIndex");
    return 0;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

String __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GetHintText(int AHintLine, int AHintCol)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GetHintText");
    return L"NoHint";
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

String __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GetOptionSetName()
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GetOptionSetName");
    return L"MyCodeInsight";
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::GotoDefinition(String &AFileName, int& ALineNum, int AIndex)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::GotoDefinition");
    return true;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightManager::Done(bool AAccepted, bool& ADisplayParams)
{
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightManager::Done");
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**my_codeinsight_symbollist.h**

```
#ifndef my_codeinsight_symbollistH
#define my_codeinsight_symbollistH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <ToolsAPI.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TMySymbolList
{
public:
    TMySymbolList(const String AText=L"", const String AType=L"", const String AClass=L"", const bool AIsReadWrite=false, const bool AIsAbstract=false, const TOTAViewerSymbolFlags AFlag=vsfUnknown, const TOTAViewerVisibilityFlags AVisibilityFlag=vvfPrivate, TOTAProcDispatchFlags AProcDispatchFlag=pdfNone)
        :   FText(AText),
            FType(AType),
            FClass(AClass),
            FFlag(AFlag),
            FVisibilityFlag(AVisibilityFlag),
            FProcDispatchFlag(AProcDispatchFlag)
        {}

    __property String                       Text                = {read=FText,              write=FText};           // i.e. 'Form1'
    __property String                       Type                = {read=FType,              write=FType};           // i.e. 'TForm1'
    __property String                       Class               = {read=FClass,             write=FClass};          // i.e. 'var', 'function', 'type', etc.
    __property bool                         IsReadWrite         = {read=FIsReadWrite,       write=FIsReadWrite};
    __property bool                         IsAbstract          = {read=FIsAbstract,        write=FIsAbstract};
    __property TOTAViewerSymbolFlags        Flag                = {read=FFlag,              write=FFlag};
    __property TOTAViewerVisibilityFlags    VisibilityFlag      = {read=FVisibilityFlag,    write=FVisibilityFlag};
    __property TOTAProcDispatchFlags        ProcDispatchFlag    = {read=FProcDispatchFlag,  write=FProcDispatchFlag};

private:
    String                      FText;
    String                      FType;
    String                      FClass;
    bool                        FIsReadWrite;
    bool                        FIsAbstract;
    TOTAViewerSymbolFlags       FFlag;
    TOTAViewerVisibilityFlags   FVisibilityFlag;
    TOTAProcDispatchFlags       FProcDispatchFlag;
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TMyCodeInsightSymbolList : public TCppInterfacedObject<IOTACodeInsightSymbolList>
{
public:
    TMyCodeInsightSymbolList();
    virtual __fastcall ~TMyCodeInsightSymbolList();

    void __fastcall Clear(void);
    int __fastcall GetCount(void);
    bool __fastcall GetSymbolIsReadWrite(int AIndex);
    bool __fastcall GetSymbolIsAbstract(int AIndex);
    TOTAViewerSymbolFlags __fastcall GetViewerSymbolFlags(int AIndex);
    int __fastcall GetViewerVisibilityFlags(int AIndex);
    TOTAProcDispatchFlags __fastcall GetProcDispatchFlags(int AIndex);
    void __fastcall SetSortOrder(const TOTASortOrder AValue);
    TOTASortOrder __fastcall GetSortOrder(void);
    int __fastcall FindIdent(const String AIdent);
    bool __fastcall FindSymIndex(const String AIdent, int& AIndex);
    void __fastcall SetFilter(const String AFilterText);
    String __fastcall GetSymbolText(int AIndex);
    String __fastcall GetSymbolTypeText(int AIndex);
    String __fastcall GetSymbolClassText(int AIndex);

    __property String SymbolClassText[int Index] = {read=GetSymbolClassText};
    __property String SymbolTypeText[int Index] = {read=GetSymbolTypeText};
    __property String SymbolText[int Index] = {read=GetSymbolText};
    __property TOTAViewerSymbolFlags SymbolFlags[int i] = {read=GetViewerSymbolFlags};
    __property int SymbolVisibility[int Index] = {read=GetViewerVisibilityFlags};
    __property bool SymbolIsAbstract[int Index] = {read=GetSymbolIsAbstract};
    __property bool SymbolIsReadWrite[int Index] = {read=GetSymbolIsReadWrite};
    __property TOTAProcDispatchFlags FuncDispatchFlags[int Index] = {read=GetProcDispatchFlags};
    __property TOTASortOrder SortOrder = {read=GetSortOrder, write=SetSortOrder};
    __property int Count = {read=GetCount};

private:
    static bool SymbolTextCompare(const TMySymbolList& AX, const TMySymbolList& AY);

    std::vector<TMySymbolList> FSymbols;
    TOTASortOrder FSortOrder;
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#endif
```

---

**my_codeinsight_symbollist.cpp**

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "my_codeinsight_symbollist.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)

// Constructor
TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::TMyCodeInsightSymbolList()
    :   FSortOrder(soAlpha)
{
    TMySymbol S;

    S.Text              = L"IAmASymbolText";
    S.Type              = L"IAmASymbolType";
    S.Class             = L"IAmASymbolClass";
    S.Flag              = vsfFunction;
    S.VisibilityFlag    = vvfPublic;

    FSymbols.push_back(S);
    FSymbols.push_back(S);
    FSymbols.push_back(S);

#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::TMyCodeInsightSymbolList");
#endif
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Destructor
__fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::~TMyCodeInsightSymbolList()
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::~TMyCodeInsightSymbolList");
#endif
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Implementor should clear its symbol list
void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::Clear(void)
{
    FSymbols.clear();
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::Clear");
#endif
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Returns the count of the symbols in the list - may be modified by setting a filter
int __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetCount(void)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetCount");
#endif
    return static_cast<int>(FSymbols.size());
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Returns whether the symbol is able to be read from and written to
bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSymbolIsReadWrite(int AIndex)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSymbolIsReadWrite");
#endif
    if (AIndex < static_cast<int>(FSymbols.size()))
        return FSymbols[AIndex].IsReadWrite;
    else
        return false;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Returns whether the symbols is abstract. Viewer draws these in the 'need to implement' color
bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSymbolIsAbstract(int AIndex)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSymbolIsAbstract");
#endif
    if (AIndex < static_cast<int>(FSymbols.size()))
        return FSymbols[AIndex].IsAbstract;
    else
        return false;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Return the symbol flags for the item at index 'AIndex'. AIndex is the index in the filtered list
TOTAViewerSymbolFlags __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetViewerSymbolFlags(int AIndex)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetViewerSymbolFlags");
#endif
    if (AIndex < static_cast<int>(FSymbols.size()))
        return FSymbols[AIndex].Flag;
    else
        return vsfUnknown;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Return the visibility flags for the item at index 'AIndex'. AIndex is the index in the filtered list
int __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetViewerVisibilityFlags(int AIndex)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetViewerVisibilityFlags");
#endif
    if (AIndex < static_cast<int>(FSymbols.size()))
        return FSymbols[AIndex].VisibilityFlag;
    else
        return vvfPrivate; // # TO DO #
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Return the procedure flags for the item at index 'AIndex'. AIndex is the index in the filtered list
TOTAProcDispatchFlags __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetProcDispatchFlags(int AIndex)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetProcDispatchFlags");
#endif
    if (AIndex < static_cast<int>(FSymbols.size()))
        return FSymbols[AIndex].ProcDispatchFlag;
    else
        return pdfNone;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// The list was requested to be sorted by 'AValue'
void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::SetSortOrder(const TOTASortOrder AValue)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::SetSortOrder");
#endif
    FSortOrder = AValue;

    // Sort order is alphabetically
    if (FSortOrder == soAlpha)
    {
        // Sort Symbol vector alphabetically
        std::sort(FSymbols.begin(), FSymbols.end(), SymbolTextCompare);
    }
    // Sort order is by scope
    else if (FSortOrder == soScope)
    {
        // Sort Symbol vector by scope
        // # TO DO #
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Returns the sort order of the list
TOTASortOrder __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSortOrder(void)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSortOrder");
#endif
    return FSortOrder;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Given an identifier, return the index of the closest partial match
int __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::FindIdent(const String AIdent)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::FindIdent");
#endif
    return 0; // # TO DO # We're not searching at the moment
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Given an identifier, find the 'Index' of an exact match in the list and return true.  Otherwise return false
bool __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::FindSymIndex(const String AIdent, int& AIndex)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::FindSymIndex");
#endif
    return false; // # TO DO # We aren't matching at the moment
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Set the lists filter to 'FilterText'. It is up to the implementor to determine how to filter or if they even want to filter
void __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::SetFilter(const String AFilterText)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::SetFilter");
#endif
    // # TO DO # : We don't filter at the moment
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Return the symbol text for item 'AIndex'. i.e. Form1
String __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSymbolText(int AIndex)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSymbolText");
#endif
    if (AIndex < static_cast<int>(FSymbols.size()))
        return FSymbols[AIndex].Text;
    else
        return L"";
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Return the symbol type text for item 'AIndex'. i.e. TForm1
String __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSymbolTypeText(int AIndex)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSymbolTypeText");
#endif
    if (AIndex < static_cast<int>(FSymbols.size()))
        return FSymbols[AIndex].Type;
    else
        return L"";
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Return the symbol class text for item 'AIndex'. i.e. 'var', 'function', 'type', etc
String __fastcall TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSymbolClassText(int AIndex)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::GetSymbolClassText");
#endif
    if (AIndex < static_cast<int>(FSymbols.size()))
        return FSymbols[AIndex].Class;
    else
        return L"";
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Returns true, if AX.Text's position is alphabetically before AY.Text's
bool TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::SymbolTextCompare(const TMySymbol& AX, const TMySymbol& AY)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    ShowMessage(L"TMyCodeInsightSymbolList::SymbolTextCompare");
#endif
    return (AnsiCompareStr(AX.Text, AY.Text) == -1);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Comment: It is clear from the error messages that NULL pointers are being accessed. You need to debug your code to find them. The fact that your `TMyCodeInsightSymbolList` destructor is getting called also suggests you are not managing that object's reference count correctly, so you need to debug that, too. I can tell you that using a `std::unique_ptr` for a reference counted object is bad. Try using `_di_IOTACodeInsightSymbolList` instead of `std::unique_ptr<TMyCodeInsightSymbolList>` if you want automatic semantics.